# How to save for each date from SQL-query -> output CSV using python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I get stuck with one issue. I'd like to write python script which connects to DB, get data and save it to each csv-file per date in result by query.

So, I've established connection to DB, I've written SQL query to get needed data. But I can't understand how I can save it to separate file.

Are there any tricks using SQL? Or how can I do that using Python?

I suppose if use Python should need loop, but how can I realize it?

I use sqlalchemy for connection, pd.read_sql() to get data (using some CTE) and then df.to_csv() to store it.

Sample data after query:

| Product_ID | Date | Price | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 241 | 2022-03-29 | 103.0 |  |
| 108 | 2022-08-11 | 57.0 | 'out of stock' |
| 93 | 2022-04-22 | 68.5 |  |
| 17 | 2022-10-17 | 1287.0 | 'the best day' |
| 359 | 2022-08-07 | 142.0 |  |
| 69 | 2022-03-29 | 132.0 |  |

So, there are 6 rows in the table above. And 5 distinct/different dates, it means that the number of output files is five.

I supposed that I can use like another CTE in this query to get datetime like `"SELECT DISTINCT("DATE") FROM result_query"`. But I don't know how to extract these date values to store it in list, for example, and after that apply filter by each date and loop df.to_csv().

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If you have the data in a dataframe then you can just filter by date and save the filtered data to your csv.

Comment: @topsail I've got the dataframe by SQL query. But how can I'll filter by date in store each date records per CSV-file like 'product_20220807.csv', 'product_20220329.csv' and etc. Can I do that using one SQL inplace? Or first I should store query to the df, then loop this df by filtering date and store to csv?

Comment: filtering a df and saving the filtered df to a csv should be very easy here.